# How to change button's size and alignment on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

I am placing 2 buttons at the bottom of a form and aligning them to the right:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12>
        <div class="pt-2 d-flex justify-content-end">
            <div class="ml-auto text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                <span class="mx-2"></span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

How can I change the `css` so that the buttons aligned to the right on `md` breakpoint but then on `xs` breakpoint the buttons expand to the whole width and placed under each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 pt-2 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-md-end">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mb-md-0 mr-md-2">Primary</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```